# CORS is blocking requests withCredentials

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

I'm new to Node and Angular. I have a problem with Cors when sending request `withCredentials: true` option. When I send such request I got:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'.`.

When sending request without this option I got no error. Angular is working on http://localhost:4200 and Nodejs is on http://localhost:1234. It seems that cors module doesn't work properly.

In the NodeJs server I use `cors` module:

```
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

req.headers at server:

```
{ host: 'localhost:1234',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '44',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  'user-agent':
   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' }
```

**EDIT** : It seems that such simple thing like running browser in private mode resolved this issue...

Comment: You could try to add your origin ( `localhost` )  to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: for a short period you can disable CORS and try this command "chrome --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials --user-data-dir=c:\chromeSession" run this using cmd or Cntr+R this is for just cross check

Comment: I'd use a proxy instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can try by setting header  like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // UI port you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    ...
}
```

UI:

```
this.http.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
```

When we pass credential to a backend service, it is mandatory to specify the url port.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this makes no difference. Error is the same.

Comment: Are you passing `{ withCredentials: true }` from UI?

Comment: Yes I'm passing { withCredentials: true } when the error appers, without { withCredentials: true } it works fine.

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry can't help further. I implemented this in .net, note node :(

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, not with this module but with sending credentials while being in development mode and using another server. I think the problem could be in the unsecured connection (`http` instead of `https`), of course, localhost is always nosecured.

I solved this for me using an proxy (`proxy.conf.json`), rerouting the url to the intended url, making the browser think, while development, that it was the same origin. 
(described here: [ANGULAR BUILD GUIDE](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server))

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://THE_OTHER_URL/WITH/PATH/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

and include it in `angular.json` under your build options for that project:

```
... 
"projects" : {
    "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" : {
        ...
        "architect": {
            ...
            "serve": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                "options": {
                    "proxyConfig" : "proxy.conf.json",
                    "browserTarget": "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME:build"
                }
            }
        },
       ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this also solves your problem, but maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

To enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in Node. CORS essentially means cross-domain requests.

Simply using this line of code to set a header on your response will enable CORS.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
});
```